# Insert div inside <td> with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, html-table

NOTE: This project's backend works with Laravel

Hi, I am trying to make a javascript function, that allows me to duplicate a `<div>` and insert it child nodes into `<tr>`, so in the end, I can use POST methods to save tables data in database.

Here's what I worked so far:

```
function newRow(id) {
    //Copy all child nodes of element with ID copyRow
    var newRow = document.getElementById('copyRow').cloneNode(true).childNodes;
    
    //Make a new element of type <tr class="product_subcategory"> </tr>
    var rowTag = document.createElement('TR');
    rowTag.className = "product_subcategory";

    //Find div where we want to add element
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(rowTag);

    //Add all childNodes to <td>, and then to <tr>
    newRow.forEach(element => {
        var data = document.createElement('TD');
        data.appendChild(element);

        rowTag.appendChild(data);
    });
}
```

And here is the `<div>` I am copying:

```
<div id="copyRow" style="display: none">
<tr class="product_subcategory">
    <td scope="row"><input class="product_subcategory_name form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type Name"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text text-muted">€</span>
            </div>
            <input name="price" id="price" class="product_subcategory_price form-control" type="number" value="0" onchange="calculateTotalPrice()" min="0" step="0.01" class="form-control @error('price') eshte jo valide @enderror" value="{{ old('price') }}" autocomplete="off" required>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><input class="product_subcategory_amount form-control" type="number" value="1" min="1"></td>
    <td>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text text-muted">€</span>
            </div>
            <input class="product_subcategory_total form-control" value="10" disabled>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After executing this js code, a new `<tr>` is added to table, and then five different empty `<td></td>` (table data tags). What I want is new `<tr>` with all child nodes of div with id="copyRow"

Comment: The `div` you are showing is incomplete. I assume there's a closing `</div>` right after what you show? Can you show what your before and after HTML is and show what result you want? At first blush, it looks like your `newRow.forEach` loop is inserting `tr` elements as children of `td` elements, which is the opposite of what should be.

Comment: Yes, it has closing div tag, I accidentally didn't copy it. It seems I can't paste all code in comment, so use this link to see it. https://justpaste.it/9ilex

What I want is js code to do is to make new <tr> with all child nodes of div with id="copyRow"

Comment: Also consider my comment about your `forEach` loop.

Comment: What have yout tried to debug the problem? How is this related to Laravel after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase - Yeah, I tried debugging. It is making a new `<tr>`, and it is adding five empty `<td>` inside `<tr>`.

Comment: That's not debugging, that's stating what is going wrong. Debugging means: what have you tried to check **why** this is going wrong? What are your attempts to **resolve** the problem?

Comment: @lurker thanks, I am considering your suggestions about forEach loop, however it seems that I can't yet solve problem

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for clarification. I actually have tried to debug code, however I don't know what is causing code not to work properly. Otherwise I would mention it in original question.

Comment: @NicoHaase Actually I just realized that when I debug element inside forEach loop, it is printing in console two empty lines.

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure what you're wanting to do. `td` elements only make sense as direct children of `tr` elements, and `tr` elements only make sense as direct children of a `tbody` or `table` element. As I was asking in my first comment, if you could show example before and after HTML, that would be help provide understanding of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use the contents of the `<div id="copyRow"> ... </div>` as a template.
UPDATE: If you are trying to do this then don't use a div. Any 'special' tags like `<tr>` and `<td>` can't exist outside of a table. But they can exist outside of a table in a `<template>` tag.

### Step 1: Replace the div with a template element.

So instead of `<div id="copyRow"> ... </div>` do `<template id="copyRow"> ... </template>`.

### Step 2: Adjust your newRow method

```
function newRow(id) {
  //Find the template
  var template = document.getElementById('copyRow');
  
  //Clone it's contents
  var newRow = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  
  //Find the table where the contents will be added
  var target = document.getElementById(id);
  
  //Append the new row
  target.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

### Step 3: Done

There, no need to mess with loops, or other stuff.

See also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: changed code as you suggested, however now method does nothing. Not an error in console, not even adding anything to table. not any change at all

Comment: Thank you mate. This was driving me crazy. Finally it is working <3